# how to create view for appointment form in footer in every page in Django

Tags: html, django

I could not add appointment data in the database

In my every html template file, I have added a footer.html like bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   <head>
   <body>
some content

{% include 'footer.html' %}
   </body>
<html>
```

in footer.html, I have mentioned the address and appointment form as above

```
<section>
<div class="fo-appointment-form">
<form  class="forms-sample" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
{% csrf_token %}
 <div>
  adress
</div>
                   
<input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Name">
                   
<input type="text" name="phone" id="id_phone_0" placeholder="Phone number">
                   
<input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" class="gui-input" placeholder="Email address">
<textarea class="gui-textarea" id="id_message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<input type="Submit" class="submit-btn" type="submit">
<form>
 </div>
</section>
```

in Django view.py

```
def Appointment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        appointment= Appointment.objects.create(
            name = request.POST.get("name"),
            phone = request.POST.get("phone"),
            email = request.POST.get("email"),
            message = request.POST.get("message"),
        )
        appointment.save()
        return redirect('same?_page')
    return render(request, 'frontend/footer.html')
```

can someone tell me how to do this? how to write view for footer? where is the mistake?

Comment: This is a good example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m55JZ3ttzI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in (action="") in the form.

you are sending the POST request to a blank link, to fix this you can remove all the (action) attribute in the form to send the request to the same view, or you can specify the exact url by using:

action="{% url 'url_name_here' %}"

Comment: thank you so much, B.OKba, It solved. I realized the mistake. I just removed the action attribute. and it solved